# How to add copy to filename if already exists?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way for if a file already exists (say `/hello.txt`) and you run the command:

```
[data writeToFile:@"/hello.txt" atomically:YES];
```

Instead of overwriting create the file `hello copy.txt` and then `hello copy 2.txt` as finder does naturally?

Comment: You have to write your own logic to do that.

Comment: What are you going to do if 'hello copy 2.txt' already exists, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use a data-writing method that will refuse to overwrite an existing file. You can use `-[NSData writeToFile:options:error:]` with the option `NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting`. Check its return value to see if it failed and then check the returned `NSError` to see if the reason it failed was an existing file. If it is, build a new path string based on the original and the number of tries you've made, adding either " copy" or " copy %u", and loop around to try again. Stop looping if you succeed or you get any other error. (You might also put a limit on the maximum number of tries, in case something unforeseen happens.)

The `NSError` indicates a failure because a file already exists at that path if its `domain` is `NSCocoaErrorDomain` and its `code` is `NSFileWriteFileExistsError`.